# dark glass/liquid problems

Tags: glass

the small project I'm working on involves a glass cup with large variations in depth, but has a square of really darkened liquid/glass, and I can't seem to fix it. I've tried the many suggestions from other posts to turn up the max light bounces, but at 1024 it makes the rest appear to glow slightly, and the center is still dark.[image: cup of T] this was based roughly on blender guru's coffee cup tutorial.

Comment: that looks like it might be a case of flipped normals or duplicate faces.  Select the mesh that the dark spot is in, go to edit mode and try SHIFT-N to recalculate normals.  If that doesn't work, maybe post your blend file in your questions ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Answer (score 0):

The biggest influencer here is **Glossy** parametr ... 0-1-2-3-4-5

[image]

Light Paths > Preset > **Limited Global Illumination**

[image]

Light Paths > Preset > **Full Global Illumination**

[image]

---

Things that makes a differens ...

... if Glass penetrates a solid object (like a floor) or not ... left T is above / right T is bellow.

[image]

... World environment ... left white color / right Image Texture.

[image]

So what worked here for Limited GI ...  Total 128, GLossy 128, Caustics enabled.